# Access Tomcat Virtual Host by ip address?

Tags: tomcat, virtualhost

I have deployed web app with a host name *[www.myApp.com](http://www.myApp.com)* on tomcat virtual host. Before I used to access this application via ip address,port and application name.In my case *[192.168.2.x/myApp](http://192.168.1.x/myApp)*. But now After setting up the virtual host and moving the appBase I couldn't do that.

Is there a way to use both ways to access my app?

Answer (score 0):

[RTFMF :)](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html)

set your www.myApp.com as defaultHost

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="www.myApp.com">
    <Host name="www.myApp.com" appBase="myApp"/>
    <Host name="stimpy" appBase="stimpyapps"/>
</Engine>
```

Comment: ya i did that.but what i really want is not that.please read the question again.thank you tho!